# Designing a Charge Amplifier Circuit in PSpice for Piezoelectric Sensor

Tags: charge, pspice, piezoelectricity

I'm new to using OrCAD PSPICE 16.6 and need some help. I'm trying to design a charge amplifier for a piezo sensor before building the actual circuit. I've chosen a VSIN source as my input to represent the sensor, and I want a gain of 10 with a frequency of 1 kHz.

I have a few questions:

1. Once I've picked component values for Cin, Cf, and Rf, how do I know
   if my output voltage is correct?
2. Does the charge amplifier amplify the voltage from my VSIN source?
   Will it turn 0.1V input into 1V output with a gain of 10?
3. Is the gain equation really A = -Cf / Cin?
4. Is my equation for Rf correct, where f = 1 / (2 * π * Rf * Cf)?
5. How do I determine the value of Cin?

As for the piezo device, I still don't have it so I don't know the specification.

I've included my circuit schematic and simulation result for reference. As you can see, I got an output voltage of -1.6662 mV (red colored sine wave), which is much lower than my expected output value (1v).

I am very confused and I'd greatly appreciate any help and guidance. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/understanding-and-implementing-charge-amplifiers-for-piezoelectric-sensor-s/

Comment: Now I know the gain is vout/q= 1/cf, but if I connect the sine generator (VSIN/SOURCE) the equation will be vout/(VAMPL) = 1/cf??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110). [File](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/18zd7q5673b8by5hy2qmq/op-amp-circuit-derivative-input-v020.cir?rlkey=jyvyqbwejrsgm5loj9n5w3dsy&dl=0) download.

You should "review" the formula.

Here is what happens when choosing the components. Here, it is a "differentiator".

[image]

Here is the results with LF13741 (FET inputs, "differentiator").

[image]

And the "transient" analysis ... "amplifier" with gain= ~ 18.

[image]

And with these values, it should be more an "amplifier", with gain = 10 (20 Hz-100 kHz).

[image]

Comment: How did you find the components values?, should I use LM741 instead of uA741?. May I see your voltage output? Will it be amplified?

Comment: You should use something as LF13741, which is a better version of LM741, with FET inputs.

Comment: Added behavior with LF13741. Yes, at this frequency (1000 Hz), it should be amplified.

Comment: Thank you for response!, but may I know how you select the C1,R1,C2 and R3 values? is it random or there is specific design equation? also I tried to do with LF13742 and your values to see how it works but I had this problem:"
ERROR(ORPSIM-15142): Node N09553 is floating

ERROR(ORPSIM-15142): Node N09542 is floating

ERROR(ORPSIM-15142): Node N093371 is floating" 


you can see the pic:
https://ibb.co/qmNYM2X

.

Comment: May I know your simulation software?

Comment: Made with microcap v12 https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110 . LF13742 does not exist ?

Comment: Ok. Little error for LF13742. Don't know for your problem "ERROR ..."

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at a stripped down version of the circuit. Ignore the lack of DC bias for now.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkvZDY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The gain is
$$ G = -{{1 \over sC2} \over {1 \over sC1}} = -{C1 \over C2} $$
The implementation of your circuit gives a gain of \$ {1 \over 16} = 0.0625 \$, not 10.

DC bias is required which is why the resistor exists between the minus input and the output. This resistor also sets the lower cutoff frequency which helps to reduce acceleration and other low frequency noises. This resistor complicates the transfer function.

Note that the impedance of a piezo transducer becomes complex at and near resonance. This further complicates the analysis. At frequencies below resonance (2 to 5 times lower) an approximate model using a voltage generator and capacitor (simple capacitance far below resonance) in series can be used as you have done.

A simulation in LTspice using a universal op-amp (behavioral model) with a gain-bandwidth product (GBW) of 1 MHz is shown below.

[image]

Note that the LM741 is not suitable for a charge amplifier due to the large input bias currents. There are ancient & modern FET input op-amps with picoamp input bias currents that would better suited for the task.